Need bound for absolute value of complex-valued special functions (Taylor coefficients of Faddeeva's w(z))
To guarantee accuracy for code [1] that computes Faddeeva's w(z) [2] using Taylor expansions around different centers, I would need upper bounds for the absolute values $|w_n(z)|$ of the coefficients
$w_n(z) := \frac{w^{(n)}(z)}{n!}$
in the first quadrant for $|z|<7$. A bound for $|w_n/w_{n-1}|$ for $n$ larger than some $N$ would be particular helpful.
The following is known about the $w_n$:
(1) With $w_0(z) = w(z)$ and $w_{-1}(z) = -i/\sqrt{\pi}$,
the recursion
$w_n = -\frac{2}{n}\left( z w_{n-1} + w_{n-2} \right)$
holds for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$
(2) For $\text{Im} z>0$,
$w_n(z) = (-1)^n \frac{i}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt\frac{e^{-t^2}}{(z-t)^n}$
(3) With the parabolic cylinder function $U$ [3],
$w_n(z) = \frac{i^n\sqrt{2}^{n+1}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,e^{-z^2/2}\,U\left(n+\frac{1}{2}, -i\sqrt{2}z\right).$
(4) From numerical tests (always for $\text{Re} z \ge0$, $\text{Im} z \ge0$, $|z|<7$) it seems pretty certain, but is not proven:

$\text{max}_z |w_0(z)| = 1$, reached at $z=0$.
$|w_1(z)|$ may be larger than $|w_0(z)|$, but for $n>1$ the $|w_n(z)|$ are strictly decreasing functions of $n$.

Short of a full answer, I would also be grateful for hints which road is most promising.
References:

[1] https://jugit.fz-juelich.de/mlz/libcerf
[2] https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.E3
[3] https://dlmf.nist.gov/12


The first answer (https://mathoverflow.net/a/482855/480439) seems to be about as good as one can get by taken absolute values of the recursion that defines the $w_n$. Unfortunately, the bounds get larger with increasing $|z|$, while the actual $|w_n(z)|$ get smaller. Therefore, bounds obtained by other methods would still be highly welcome.

For $n=1,2,\dots$, using the inequalities
$$|w_n|\le\frac{2}{n}( |z| |w_{n-1}| + |w_{n-2}| )$$
and
$$r_n:=\frac{\Gamma(n/2+1)}{n \Gamma(n/2+1/2)}\le r_1=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2},$$
by induction on $n$ we see that
$$|w_n|\le W_n:=c\frac{a^n}{\Gamma(n/2+1)},$$
where
$$a:=\frac{|z|\sqrt\pi+\sqrt{|z|^2\pi+4}}{2},\quad c:=\max\Big(|w_0|,\frac{\sqrt\pi\,|w_1|}{2a}\Big).$$

Indeed, the inequality $r_n\le r_1$ holds for $n=1,2,\dots$ because $r_2<r_1$ and $r_{n+2}=\frac n{n+1}\,r_n<r_n$ for $n=1,2,\dots$.
Next, it is easy to see that $|w_n|\le W_n$ for $n=0,1$. Suppose now that $|w_k|\le W_k$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ and $k=0,\dots,n-1$. Then for $n=1,2,\dots$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
|w_n|&\le\frac{2}{n}( |z| |w_{n-1}| + |w_{n-2}| ) \\ 
&\le\frac{2}{n}( |z| W_{n-1} + W_{n-2} ) \\ 
&=\Big(2\frac{|z|}a\,r_n+\frac1{a^2}\Big)W_n  \\ 
&\le\Big(2\frac{|z|}a\,r_1+\frac1{a^2}\Big)W_n =W_n, 
\end{aligned}$$
so that $|w_n|\le W_n$. $\quad\Box$

The upper bound $W_n$ on $|w_n|$ converges fast down to $0$ for large $n$.

While you extended your answer, I already checked and confirmed your first version. Many thanks. I just wonder whether the bound can be made sharper by using Gautschi's inequality DLMF 5.6.4, $\Gamma(x+1)/\Gamma(x+s)<(x+1)^{1-s}$.

@JoachimW : I think that, along mostly the same lines -- but using the inequality $r_n<\dfrac1n,\sqrt{\dfrac{n+1}2}$, the bound can indeed be made sharper: with a smaller value of $a$ and possibly with an extra factor like $n^b$ for some real $b>0$ not depending on $n$.

Factor $n^b$ doesn't work out. But we may replace $\sqrt{\pi}$ by $\sqrt{1+2/N}$, and the resulting bound will hold for $n\ge N$.

Because $r_n\to0$, we can replace $a$ by $\tilde a>1$ however close to $1$ for $n>N$, but then $c$ will depend on $N$.
